# Multi and Parallel Monte Carlo fail with key error (on database name)

Tags: brightway

I am trying to use Brightway's `ParallelMonteCarlo`and `MultiMonteCarlo`class but have run into a KeyError. I am in a Brightway project with an LCI database:

```
In  [1] bw.databases
Out [1] Brightway2 databases metadata with 2 objects:
           biosphere3
           ecoinvent 3_2 CutOff
```

Selecting an activity and a method:

```
In [2]  db = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3_2 CutOff')
        act = db.random()
        method = ('CML 2001', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')
```

My code is as follows:

```
In [3]  ParallelMC_LCA = bw.ParallelMonteCarlo({act:1}, 
                                              method = myMethod,
                                              iterations=1000,
                                              cpus=mp.cpu_count())
        results = np.array(ParallelMC_LCA.calculate())
```

and

```
In [4]  act1 = db.random()
        act2 = db.random()
        multiMC_LCA = bw.MultiMonteCarlo(demands = [{act1:1}, {act2:1}],
                                        method = myMethod, 
                                        iterations = 10)
        results = np.array(ParallelMC_LCA.calculate())
```

Both give me a `KeyError: 'ecoinvent 3_2 CutOff'`.

My question is: why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue due to differences in how multiprocessing works on Windows and Unix](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/issues/5/multiprocessing-and-projects-conflict-on). Specifically, on Windows the project is not set correctly, causing a `KeyError`. As such, it isn't a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Agree, and will report bugs elsewhere from now on.

Comment: Multiprocessing should now work in _most_ cases thanks to a [project names being explicitly passed to workers](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-calc/commits/e217412870d04bdab560814d42be6ce6845ee144). However, if you set a custom directory using an environment variable you might still have problems.